# Android - Make Toast from another Class for Main Activity

Tags: android, timer, toast

I have already searched all day for a solution. Unfortunately, have not found anything that can help me.

I have to change every 15 minutes ago values​​. I would not do in my main activity, but now a different class.
I thought something like that would be no problem, but I am stuck.
I wanted to print a test message, but there's something wrong with the given context. Possibly I have a general problem with my "timer".

Heres my Code:

Main Activity:

```
tm = new TimerLoerg(this.getApplicationContext());
tm.startTimer();
```

And here my Timer Class (not finished)

```
package at.android.dertestloerk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class TimerLoerg extends Activity{

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    int ms;
    Toast toast;

    private ImageView imageViewLoerg;
    private AnimationDrawable animatedLoerg;

    private Context context;
    Activity activity;

    public TimerLoerg(Context context, Activity activity){
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        ms = 5000;
        handler.postDelayed(timedTask, ms);

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Timer gestartet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void changeLoerg() {
        int stufe;
        // layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutMain);
        imageViewLoerg = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLoerg);

        stufe = SettingsLoerg.getLevel(context);

        Object tag = imageViewLoerg.getTag();

        if (stufe == 1) {
            int loergId = R.drawable.animatedegg;

            if( tag != null && ((Integer)tag).intValue() == loergId) {
                loergId = R.drawable.animatedloerg;
                animatedLoerg.stop();
                //playAnimationNodelay();
                imageViewLoerg.setTag(loergId);
                imageViewLoerg.setBackgroundResource(loergId);
                playAnimationNodelay();
            }
        }
    }

    public void changeStats() {
        int hunger;

        hunger = SettingsLoerg.getHunger(context);
        if (hunger < 15) {
            toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Loerg is very hungry!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        else {
            hunger = hunger - 15;
            SettingsLoerg.setHunger(hunger, context);
        }
    }

    private void playAnimation() {
        if (this.imageViewLoerg.getDrawable() instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
            this.animatedLoerg = (AnimationDrawable)this.imageViewLoerg.getDrawable();
            Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    animatedLoerg.start();              
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    }

    private void playAnimationNodelay() {
        if (this.imageViewLoerg.getDrawable() instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
            this.animatedLoerg = (AnimationDrawable)this.imageViewLoerg.getDrawable();
            animatedLoerg.start();
        }
    }

    private Runnable timedTask = new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run() {
           changeLoerg();
           handler.postDelayed(timedTask, 5000);
          }};
}
```

Log:

```
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at at.android.dertestloerk.TimerLoerg$2.run(TimerLoerg.java:29)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-05 20:33:02.521: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Timer class is not linked to a layout as you can see. I do not know if could cause problems? I just needed some methods of activity.

Comment: Just a warning - you don't need to hold a reference to the Context since that can leak memory really easily. Using this in place of your context variable should be fine if you're using the activity class correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assign a value to the `toast` field. When you access it in `toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);` you get a null pointer exception.

Comment: *super facepalm* That was it really. I'm such an idiot. Thank you. I would probably still searched forever.

Comment: i changed it to: toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Timer gestarte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          toast.show();

Comment: @SettusBlake: edit your post with whole TimerLoerg class code

Comment: @SettusBlake: logcat is latest or old?

Comment: @SettusBlake:also remove  `extends Activity`

Answer (score 0):

What about just passing the var "context"

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        run { Sec().main(context = context) }
}
```

Sec.kt

```
class Sec(){
    fun main(context: Context ) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "hello from class sec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```