# Android - Change BackgroundResource from Imageview in other class

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview

I wanted (inherited from Activity) via a second class to access an ImageView and change it.
Unfortunately I get a NullPointerExeption when I attempt this.
The second class has no XML and no onCreate () method. It inherits from Activity only because I need some functions.

So how do you access a layout or other components?

Here is the code of my second class.

```
public void changeLoerg() {
    int stufe;
    //layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutMain);
    imageViewLoerg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLoerg);

    stufe = SettingsLoerg.getLevel(context);

    Object tag = imageViewLoerg.getTag();

    if (stufe == 1) {
        int loergId = R.drawable.animatedegg;

        if( tag != null && ((Integer)tag).intValue() == loergId) {
            loergId = R.drawable.animatedloerg;
            animatedLoerg.stop();
            //playAnimationNodelay();
            imageViewLoerg.setTag(loergId);
            imageViewLoerg.setBackgroundResource(loergId);
            playAnimationNodelay();
        }
    }
}
```

Und hier das LogCat:

```
01-05 21:34:39.685: W/dalvikvm(9905): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b5b300)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at at.android.dertestloerk.TimerLoerg.changeLoerg(TimerLoerg.java:42)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at at.android.dertestloerk.TimerLoerg$1.run(TimerLoerg.java:100)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-05 21:34:39.693: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `changeLoerg()` method is inside `TimerLoerg` class which also extending Activity class ?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, I had forgotten to write that.

Comment: you can't access anything in another `Activity`. where is this `ImageView` in relation to your current `Activity`?

Comment: Hm, i see. is there no possible way?

Comment: @SettusBlake : i mean see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175550/android-make-toast-from-another-class-for-main-activity) and chnage your TimerLoerg as in answer and use `(ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLoerg);` to access imageview in non activity class

Comment: i'm sure there's a way to do what you wish but not in the way that you're doing it. why don't you let us know what you're attempting to do with this second "Activity" and the views inside of it and we can show you how it can be done in other ways.

Comment: the background is an animated picture (xml file with two pictures). i want to change that animated picture with an other after x seconds. (sorry, my english is bad)

Comment: But I did not have everything in a Main Activity class. So I created a separate class where all my methods come in, having to do with the fact that every 15 minutes to be changed something.

Comment: @mango : i already give solution to access all UI elements in non activity class but OP avoid it you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175550/android-make-toast-from-another-class-for-main-activity)

Comment: ok thanks K. Object tag = imageViewLoerg.getTag(); is null. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class with this `View` that you want to modify, you should create a method within that class to modify said `View`. Then you can call the method in your `Activity` and pass in whatever you need as a parameter.

```
public class BackGround { // please don't extend Activity unless it is one

    private ImageView img;

    ....

    public void changeLoerg(int resourceId) {
        img.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);      
    }
}
```